# bootstrap Nav tabs with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap Nav Tabs and Tab panes on my site. There are some spots on the site I'd like to add extra links that activate the Tab Panes. I have that working fine, what I can't figure out is how I can have that same link scroll to that Pane, I think because of this line in the bootstrap.js

```
    if (showEvent.isDefaultPrevented() || hideEvent.isDefaultPrevented())
```

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7q4kw41o/) to show what I'm trying to acheive. There is a button at the bottom of the page that will activate the second pane.

I'm also using the jquery easing plugin to acheive the smooth scrolling. Once the ".page-scroll" link activates the pane, the second click will scroll properly, I guess I need these to happen on the same click.

Thanks,

Comment: scroll to where?..the fiddle works...whats the problem?

Comment: It only works on the second click. I need it to work on the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// I got this from http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
     $('ul.nav li').removeClass('active');
     $('.tab-content .tab-pane').removeClass('active');
     $('[aria-controls="profile"]').parent().addClass('active');
        $('.tab-content #profile').addClass('active');
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

// all the relevant parts from bootstrap.js 
+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // TAB CLASS DEFINITION
  // ====================

  var Tab = function (element) {
    this.element = $(element)
  }

  Tab.VERSION = '3.3.2'

  Tab.TRANSITION_DURATION = 150

  Tab.prototype.show = function () {
    var $this    = this.element
    var $ul      = $this.closest('ul:not(.dropdown-menu)')
    var selector = $this.data('target')

    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') // strip for ie7
    }

    if ($this.parent('li').hasClass('active')) return

    var $previous = $ul.find('.active:last a')
    var hideEvent = $.Event('hide.bs.tab', {
      relatedTarget: $this[0]
    })
    var showEvent = $.Event('show.bs.tab', {
      relatedTarget: $previous[0]
    })

    $previous.trigger(hideEvent)
    $this.trigger(showEvent)

    if (showEvent.isDefaultPrevented() || hideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    var $target = $(selector)

    this.activate($this.closest('li'), $ul)
    this.activate($target, $target.parent(), function () {
      $previous.trigger({
        type: 'hidden.bs.tab',
        relatedTarget: $this[0]
      })
      $this.trigger({
        type: 'shown.bs.tab',
        relatedTarget: $previous[0]
      })
    })
  }

  Tab.prototype.activate = function (element, container, callback) {
    var $active    = container.find('> .active')
    var transition = callback
      && $.support.transition
      && (($active.length && $active.hasClass('fade')) || !!container.find('> .fade').length)

    function next() {
      $active
        .removeClass('active')
        .find('> .dropdown-menu > .active')
          .removeClass('active')
        .end()
        .find('[data-toggle="tab"]')
          .attr('aria-expanded', false)

      element
        .addClass('active')
        .find('[data-toggle="tab"]')
          .attr('aria-expanded', true)

      if (transition) {
        element[0].offsetWidth // reflow for transition
        element.addClass('in')
      } else {
        element.removeClass('fade')
      }

      if (element.parent('.dropdown-menu')) {
        element
          .closest('li.dropdown')
            .addClass('active')
          .end()
          .find('[data-toggle="tab"]')
            .attr('aria-expanded', true)
      }

      callback && callback()
    }

    $active.length && transition ?
      $active
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', next)
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Tab.TRANSITION_DURATION) :
      next()

    $active.removeClass('in')
  }


  // TAB PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // =====================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      var data  = $this.data('bs.tab')

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.tab', (data = new Tab(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.tab

  $.fn.tab             = Plugin
  $.fn.tab.Constructor = Tab


  // TAB NO CONFLICT
  // ===============

  $.fn.tab.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.tab = old
    return this
  }


  // TAB DATA-API
  // ============

  var clickHandler = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    Plugin.call($(this), 'show')
  }

  $(document)
    .on('click.bs.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"]', clickHandler)
    .on('click.bs.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="pill"]', clickHandler)

}(jQuery);
```

```css
.tab-content {
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
    min-height:300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<div id="top" style="height:700px;border:1px solid #000;">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content"  id="over">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">Bla bla bla</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
/* I know the active class on the Nav Tabs won't work but the way my site is layed out that's okay*/
<button role="presentation">
    <a href="#over" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="page-scroll">Up Top</a>
</button>
```

Comment: The scroll works but now the second tab, "#profile" doesn't open. I was hoping to have both actions performed on the first click of my ".page-scroll" link.

Comment: Hi matt please see this.
Hope this helps. If you have a question, or if you don't understand something, feel free to ask.

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you, much appreciated.